# Russian Bold Characters are not displayed

Tags: flash, apache-flex, unicode

I am working on a multilingual application in flex. It works when there is normal characters such as "Количество полевых визитов" but when the same text becomes bold. It does not work.

I have Flex 3.6A and Flash Player 15.0.0

What will be the possible solution?

Comment: Do you use embeded fonts?

Comment: `It does not work.`  Could you be more specific?  e.g. the text doesn't display at all vs. displaying not bold?

Comment: Use a unicode-capable font like Arial. Make sure you are embedding the font and that "bold" face is supported/included. Also you can try increase/decrease text size just incase some weird stuff is happening (like characters disappearing if font size is +1 bigger than regular size)

Comment: @Brian The text is not displayed at all.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this CSS code, the last statement is meant for the mobile app:

```
@namespace s "library://ns.adobe.com/flex/spark";
@namespace mx "library://ns.adobe.com/flex/mx";

@font-face { 
    src: url("/assets/fonts/arial.ttf"); 
    fontFamily: embFont;
    embedAsCFF: false; /* required for StyleableTextField */
    unicodeRange:
        U+0020-U+0040, /* Punctuation, Numbers */
        U+0041-U+005A, /* Upper-Case A-Z */
        U+0061-U+007A, /* Lower-Case a-z */
        U+0410-U+0451; /* Cyrillic */   
}

s|LabelItemRenderer {
    fontFamily: embFont;
}
```